# Input restrictions for Chosen jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the following code to restrict input (to alphanumeric) into a text field:

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

The above code works great on a standard input field, but when I type into a field generated by Chosen, the function is not applied. The chosen plugin does generate a div containing `<input type="text">` but `$('input')` doesn't seem to touch it. I'm guessing this is due to the timing of when the above code is applied..

Comment: can't you give a 'class' attribute to your 'input' feilds ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack's answer works. But the important thing to understand is that the keypress event bubbles, so you can catch it anywhere up the node hierarchy, at a node that is not generated dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/KWv7Z/6/

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (event) {
    // Will fire for all elements, we only care for inputs
    // Also allow navigation keypresses
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != "INPUT" ||
            $.inArray(event.which, [8,9,13,16,17,18,19,20,27,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46]) ) {
      return;
    }
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    // jQuery already normalizes event.which
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

This is also more memory friendly since it doesn't install a separate handler per input on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson Juan. Really valuable, but it looks like it doesn't do the trick the chosen input field =(

Comment: @Abram: Which part doesn't work? There was a small bug in the previous version. See the JSFiddle in the answer.

Comment: I will try this at home with the chosen plugin loaded up. I tried to load it up using the add a resource option on JSFiddle, but to no avail.

Comment: Not sure what you changed from before but it works now. Thanks a million Juan!

Comment: Oh hey, any idea what might be stopping me from using backspace in firefox? Works perfect in Chrome. BTW I added a space ("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$") but this isn't what broke it.

Comment: @Abram Actually no navigation was being allowed at all. Fixed the example so it does allow navigation, insert, home, end and all that good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.bind()`, consider using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which will work for elements that are created dynamically.

Comment: Sorry Jack, doesn't work for my case. It's something about the way chosen works I guess :(